# Create a VM inventory with extra column for Snapshot status?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am still learning powershell and powercli, but wondering if anyone could help me with this.

I am trying to display (eventually export to csv) an inventory of *ALL* VMs with a column for Snapshot with value of "yes" if snapshot is present (not null).

I have the extra column created and output to csv:

```
Get-VM | select Name, PowerState, Snapshot | Export-Csv -Path "c:\VMs\vminventory.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

And how to get a "yes" if Snapshot is not null:

```
$VMs = Get-VM
ForEach ($VM in $VMs) {
$VMSnapshot = Get-VM -name $VM | get-Snapshot
If ($VMSnapshot) {Write-Host "yes" }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas of how to combine these concepts to output something like this?

[VM Inventory Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4IkU.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this will work (I don't have PowerCli to test). What happens here is you add new property to the object and export the object to csv. you could probably construct the property on the fly.

I've also removed the extra call to get-vm, should save a lot of time.

```
$VMs = Get-VM
ForEach ($VM in $VMs) {
    $VMSnapshot = $vm | Get-Snapshot
    If ($VMSnapshot) {
        $row = $VM | select Name,Powerstate
        $row | Add-Member-MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Snapshot" -Value "Yes"
        $row | Export-CSV -Path "c:\VMs\vminventory.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

if you need to export all vm's (not only those with snapshot), do this:

```
$VMs = Get-VM
ForEach ($VM in $VMs) {
    $VMSnapshot = $vm | Get-Snapshot
    $row = $VM | select Name,Powerstate
    If ($VMSnapshot) {
        $row | Add-Member-MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Snapshot" -Value "Yes"
    }
    else {
        $row | Add-Member-MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Snapshot" -Value "No"
    }
    $row | Export-CSV -Path "c:\VMs\vminventory.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Wow that is really close!!  Thanks for responding.  But I need all of the VMs listed (11 of them), with yes in the Snapshot column for only the ones that have one (6 of them).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks!  So far, I get this error.  Researching...  Export-CSV : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: c:\VMs\vminventory.csv. The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: Snapshot. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and 
then retry the command.

Comment: Yes -force worked when I added it to the end.  Final code above.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: ok, so you should probably accept this as an answer ;) @Oneil

Answer (score -1):

Thank you!!!!!!!!  Final code here:

```
$VMs = Get-VM
ForEach ($VM in $VMs) {
    $VMSnapshot = $vm | Get-Snapshot
    $row = $VM | select Name,Powerstate
    If ($VMSnapshot) {
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Snapshot" -Value "Yes"
    }
    $row | Export-CSV -Path "c:\VMs\vminventory.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```